# Uniformely distribute as many items as possible among a set of carriers

Tags: algorithm

**Problem**:

- there n boxes b_1, ... b_n
- box b_i has weight w_i and cost c_i
- there are m persons p_1, .... p_m
- person p_i has strength s_i and money m_i, and so she/he can carry a number of boxes such that the sum of their weights is less than or equal to s_i, and the sum of their costs is less than or equal to m_i

How do I distribute the boxes among the persons such that the maximum number of boxes is uniformly distributed among the m persons? In other words, I want to distribute as many boxes as possible (ideally all the n boxes) among the  m persons, in such a way that all the persons uses approximately the same strength to carry the weight of their respective boxes, and spend approximately the same amount of money to take them.

**Questions**:

1. what kind of problem is this? It looks like a [Bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing), but I think it's different
2. What is a good algorithm to solve it?

Comment: Consider moving to [Computer Science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Does each person have the same strength and money? Your request for "that all the persons uses approximately the same" makes this ambiguous.

Comment: @LastCoder: each person may have different amount of strength and money. The requirement "that all the persons uses approximately the same" means that I should minimize the difference between the strength (and money) used by any two different persons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [multiobjective optimization problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization).

The objectives are:

1. Distribute as many boxes as possible
2. All the persons uses approximately the same strength
3. All the persons uses approximately the same money

and the constrains:

1. Weight of each box
2. Strength of each person
3. Money of each person

It looks like a variation of a [multiple-constraints multiple-nested-knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems).